# How can i use SQL Server Functions with EF Core Power Tools

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-function, ef-power-tools

I am using EF Core Power Tools in my asp.net web application. After using it for a long time for my models and procedures, I wanted to use it for my existing database functions. I loaded the functions in the same way as the procedures and models in my project, when I wanted to call the functions with the following code I noticed that the generated functions are not implemented.I have searched the internet and have not found  a way to use the functions from my SQL Server. Is there a way to load it with EF Core Power Tools?

**How i want to call function**

```
 var x = ASB_ZentralContext.GET_UST_Text(customerId, articleId);
```

**Generated function code**

```
 public partial class ZentralContext
   {

    [DbFunction("GET_UST_Satz", "dbo")]
    public static double? GET_UST_Satz(int? Zahler_ID, int? Artikel_ID)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This method can only be called from Entity Framework Core queries");
    }

    [DbFunction("GET_UST_Text", "dbo")]
    public static string GET_UST_Text(int? Zahler_ID, int? Artikel_ID)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This method can only be called from Entity Framework Core queries");
    }

    protected void OnModelCreatingGeneratedFunctions(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
    }
}
```

I tried id like this:

i added this in my DbContext

```
   public int Get_UST_Satz(int zahler_ID, int artikel_id)
 => throw new NotSupportedException();
```

and this in my dbContext ModelBuilder

```
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(Context).GetMethod(nameof(Get_UST_Satz), new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) }))
                .HasName("GET_UST_Satz");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a scalar value, so you cannot treat it as a table.

See the [EF Core docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping#mapping-a-method-to-a-sql-function) and the sample code in the [Power Tools wiki](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools/wiki/Reverse-Engineering#sql-server-stored-procedures)

```
var result = db.Orders.Where(o => o.Reference == NorthWindContext.GetReference(o.OrderName)).ToList();
```

Comment: Do i have to call it like this from my `DatabaseContext` or in my `Repository` , and i dont know where this `Orders` comes from.

Comment: I Uppdated my post with my code.